# While function in echo

Tags: php

I have some php code that looks like :

```
echo"
<tr>
<td colspan=\"2\">" . get_comment(${'imgmodp_data_' . $i}['primid']) . "</td>
</tr>
 ";
```

My `get_comment` function:

```
function get_comment($primid)
{
    $dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "something", "something", "something");
    $sql = "SELECT `id_sheep`, `text` FROM `comments` WHERE `primid`='$primid'";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        return = "<div>" . $row['text'] . "</div></br>";
    }
}
```

But this only returns one row each time even if they is multiple rows. If I use `echo` instead of `return` it returns all lines but at the top of my document, not in the blocks where it should be...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable before your loop, which you update inside your loop and return after your loop.

If you just use return, you'll stop the function, so after 1 loop.
With echo you output the string directly, but don't stop the loop.

For example:

```
function get_comment($primid){
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "something", "something", "something");
$sql = "SELECT `id_sheep`, `text` FROM `comments` WHERE `primid`='$primid'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
$return = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $return .= "<div>" . $row['text'] . "</div></br>";
}
return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
echo "<div>" . $row['text'] . "</div></br>";
```

and place the php code where you want it to show.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <!-- PHP code goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As i said; i gives me all the lines but at the top of the document .
Maybe because its an echo in an echo

Comment: @Jackymamouth check now

Comment: my html content is generated by an echo, that was the problem